# SVN - Error Rep Repository UUID 'XXX...' doesn't match expected 'XXX..'

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Zend Framework's SVN server went down yesterday, now it's back I'm still getting an error from my external 'Zend' directory. Whenever I try to update or switch to another branch I get this error.

```
Error     Repository UUID 'XXXX...' doesn't match expected 
Error     UUID 'XXXX...'
```

The UUIDs are different to each other.

I am using tortoiseSVN client, but I believe this is an SVN error.

Comment: I described one way to solve it here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12284894/commit-failed-repository-uuid-doesnt-match-expected-uuid-when-co/27070370#27070370][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12284894/commit-failed-repository-uuid-doesnt-match-expected-uuid-when-co/27070370#27070370

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've not used Zend's server, but this is an SVN error. Your working copy is tied to the repository of the UUID from which it was initially created. The error means the UUID has changed on the server since your WC was created.

This usually happens when a dump/load cycle has been done on the server and the UUID of the repository wasn't preserved.

There's two way to remedy this. On the client side:

```
 svn switch --relocate
```

Will relocate your WC to the new repository (which I'm assuming should be the old one). I think Tortoise has a separate `relocate` option, rather than just `switch`.

Or, on the server:

```
svnadmin setuuid <repository path> <new uuid>
```

You can set the UUID of the repo to the old one and your existing WC should then start talking to it again. (`svn info` inside your WC will show you the UUID it's expecting.)

The former option is what you need if you're not in control of the repo, the latter if you are in control of it. (Other clients would be seeing the same issue).

More detail on repository UUIDs here: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.uuids

Comment: This option no longer exists.

Comment: `relocate` fails with the same error....

Answer (score 1):

Well depends what happened when it went down. As the UUID's are different i guess they recreated the repository and somehow it got given a different UUID.

If you have access to the underlying svn repository you can set the repository UUID to be as it was using:-

```
 svnadmin setuuid REPOS_PATH [NEW_UUID]
```

Otherwise the other solution is to get a fresh checkout from the new repository.

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial in  [SVN-relocate-error-invalid-relocation-destination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28117615/svn-relocate-error-invalid-relocation-destination) works for me.

Try deleted the .svn folder and ran `svn checkout <new-url-of-branch>`