# Trying to make switch on folder to one repository from another repository and getting error SVN - Error Rep Repository UUID

Tags: svn

I'm getting same error as described here [SVN - Error Rep Repository UUID 'XXX...' doesn't match expected 'XXX..'](https://serverfault.com/questions/248495/svn-error-rep-repository-uuid-xxx-doesnt-match-expected-xxx), but I think, that conditions are a bit different. I have one local Subversion repository, that is located at `svn://ip_address/repo1_name/branches/Folder` and the other one where I'm trying to make switch `svn://ip_address/repo2_name/trunk/Folder`.

So I checked out this `svn://ip_address/repo2_name/trunk` as a new project and then tryed to do a switch on directory `Folder` to this address `svn://ip_address/repo1_name/branches/Folder`. Since, that attempt I've been getting error described earlier. I tryed to do, what was suggested there. `--relocate` didn't help me much and setting new uuid wasn't an option since I don't know the previous one.

I thought, that it might be due to a different repositories ( directory, that I was switching to is in another repository ), but later I thought, that this shouldn't be an issue.

Any points to how might I solve this problem?
Thanks in advance to all who could help.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? It look like you're trying to use a folder on a different repository as a branch of the trunk on the first one. Is there a reason why you can't just create a branch on the same repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(following discussion in chat)

What you're trying to achieve isn't what the switch and relocate commands are for. `switch` will point your working copy at another point in the *same* repository which will allow you to move quickly to a branch without having to make a fresh checkout. The UUID error results when you try to switch between two WCs from two different repositories.

`relocate` will change your working copy *root* to a new repository. Useful if you've changed scheme or move the repo to a new host.

Branching and merging is what's needed to track changes between two parts of the same repository. This is well documented and a core feature of svn, but there's a good example of a reintegration merge as example 3 in `svn help merge`.

The other option is to use an external on the second repo to pull down changes to repo1 as part of any update to repo2.

Comment: Awesome. Now it is clear.

Comment: Also one more thing. Will I be able to make changes ( commit changes to this directory ) to the directory, that was pulled as `svn:external` or I'm only like listener and will be able only to pull updates?

Comment: An external is just a pointer to another repository. As long as you have permissions to write the the main repository, then you can write to the external as well.

Comment: Odd. Co-worker told me today, that I can only pool changes if there is `svn:external` specified, but I woun't be able to commit changes to that folder ( to the branch where it was downloaded from ).

Answer (score 1):

Actually it sounds like the error is exactly that they are different repositories.

What I would do if I were doing this is check out the folder you want to move, and then delete the .svn hidden folder in your checked out copy, and add all the files to the destination repository as new.

Comment: I also would like to commit to both directories depending on where changes are made.